# Error in champ.lasso of ChAMP Bioconductor package for Methylation 450k analysis

Tags: r, dataframe, bioconductor, genetics, genome

I have just installed ChAMP and all of its dependencies for methylation 450k analysis.

I was trying out the tutorial (http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ChAMP/inst/doc/ChAMP.pdf) but got an error.

When running the Probe Lasso DMR Hunter, I encounter "You have found 4161 significant MVPs with a BH adjusted P-value below 0.05
Error in `[.data.frame`(dmr.beta.means, , 22:24, ) : 
  undefined columns selected"

The error prevents halts the analysis, and I can't replicate what is shown in the above-mentioned tutorial.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing ChAMP, to no avail...

Any advice and insight will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

using R 3.1.0, the error can be solved.

Comment: Many thanks - indeed, the problem appears to lie with R 3.2.1. I re-installed R 3.1.0, and there's no such problem.